# Circle class multiple constructors

Tags: java

I am trying  modify the class Circle to include a third constructor for constructing a Circle instance with two arguments - a double for radius and a String for color. Also Modify the main class to construct an instance of Circle using this constructor. I am having trouble with this, i keep getting the message that constructor Circle is never used. Please have a look at the code.

```
 public class Circle {
        private double radius;
        private String color;


        public Circle() {
            radius = 1.0;
            color = "red";
        }


        public Circle(double r) {
            radius = r;
            color = "Blue";
        }

        public Circle(double r, String c) {
            radius = r;
            color =c;
        }



        public double getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(double newRadius) {
            radius = newRadius;
        }


        public String getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String newColor) {
            color=newColor;
        }



        public double getArea() {
            return radius*radius*Math.PI;
        }
    }

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Circle c1 = new Circle();
            System.out.println("The circle has radius of " +     c1.getRadius());
            System.out.println("and area of " + c1.getArea());

            Circle c2 = new Circle(2.5);
            System.out.println("The circle has radius of " + c2.getRadius());
            System.out.println("and area of " + c2.getArea());


            Circle c3 = new Circle(0.5);
            c3.setColor("Green");
            System.out.println("The circle has radius of " 
            + c3.getRadius());
            System.out.println("and area of " + c3.getArea());
            System.out.println("color is: " + c3.getColor());




            Circle c5 = new Circle();
            c5.setRadius(500.0);
            System.out.println("radius is: " + c5.getRadius());
            c5.setColor("Yellow");
            System.out.println("color is: " + c5.getColor());


        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not using the third constructor overload `Circle(double r, String c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you aren't using it, so the message should hardly be a surprise. Just stick in a call to the two-argument constructor somewhere (e.g., `Circle c3 = new Circle(0.5, "Green");`), and the message should go away. Of course, if you change all the instance creations to the two-argument constructor, you'll then get the warning for the zero- and one-argument versions.

Alternatively, you can change your constructor definitions:

```
public class Circle {
    public Circle() {
        this(1.0, "red");
    }


    public Circle(double r) {
        this(r, "Blue");
    }

    public Circle(double r, String c) {
        radius = r;
        color = c;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have to say, though, that it's weird to have the default value for the color be "red" when you use a default radius and "Blue" when you specify a radius. I would recommend against that, in which case I'd change the first constructor to:

```
public Circle() {
    this(1.0);
}
```

You might also want to look at using an `enum` for your colors, to avoid problems with case differences (like "red" vs. "Red"). You can always convert between an `enum` value and a `String` using the built-in `enum` methods `name()` and `valueOf(String)`.